# Unsupported media type exception while sending request to the Webapi using post method

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to upload image to the server but I am getting 'unsupported media type exception'. Here I am try to upload images bytes as dto and I am using postmethod. Here is the sample code I am using.

### Sample code for upload image to server:

```
public static async Task<T> UploadProfilePic<T>(string apiUrl, FileDto fileDto)
{
    try
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(ApplicationApiUrls.AppWebUrl);

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + ApplicationContext.AccessToken);

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));//ACCEPT header

            string filename = fileDto.FileName;

            MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            ByteArrayContent imageContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileDto.ImageBytes);

            imageContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = filename
            };

            content.Add(imageContent);

            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(ApplicationApiUrls.AppWebUrl + apiUrl), content);

            var stringAsync = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseJson = stringAsync;

                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseJson);
            }

            LoggingManager.Error("Received error response: " + stringAsync);
            return default(T);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

### Server method :

```
  [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("UpdateProfilePicFromMobile")]
    public ResponseViewModel UpdateProfilePicFromMobile(FileDto fileDto)
    {
        try
        {
            int userId = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();

            var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0 ? HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0] : null;

            if (userId > 0 && fileDto != null && file?.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var imageManager =  new ImageManager();
                imageManager.SaveImage(file.InputStream, file.FileName, ImageTypes.ProfilePicture);

                return new ResponseViewModel() { success = true, id = pid.ToString(), message = "Image updated successfully." };
            }

            return new ResponseViewModel() { success = false, id = "", message = "Sorry, Image faile to update." };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);

            return new ResponseViewModel() { success = false, id = "", message = "Sorry, Image faile to update." +"/ " + ex.Message };
        }
    }
```

### Dto class :

```
public class FileDto
{
    public string FileName {get;set;}

    public byte[] ImageBytes { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string ImageFullPath { get; set; }
 }
```

[image]

I am using post method in server for saving image. Please suggest any idea, what I am missing.

Comment: Can we see the server method you're targeting? What should it accept?

Comment: Hi ADyson, I have update the question with server method.

Comment: what does FileDto look like? That's quite important.

Comment: In 'fileDto' I am adding fallowing fields i.e 1. ImageBytes, 2. FileName, 3.FilePath

Comment: add the full class definition to the question please, i.e. with the data types as well

Comment: Hi ADyson, I have added file dto full class.

Answer (score 0):

Web Api does not support 'multipart/form-data' media type (which you send) by default. So you need to [process the request body directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2).
I've updated your server method. Now it can read sended file

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("UpdateProfilePicFromMobile")]
public ResponseViewModel UpdateProfilePicFromMobile()
{
    try
    {
        int userId = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();

        var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0 ? HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0] : null;

        if (userId > 0 && file?.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var imageManager = new ImageManager();
            imageManager.SaveImage(file.InputStream, file.FileName, ImageTypes.ProfilePicture);

            return new ResponseViewModel() { success = true, id = pid.ToString(), message = "Image updated successfully." };
        }

        return new ResponseViewModel() { success = false, id = "", message = "Sorry, Image faile to update." };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);

        return new ResponseViewModel() { success = false, id = "", message = "Sorry, Image faile to update." + "/ " + ex.Message };
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, Thanks for reply. I have very little knowledge on web api's. can you please please explain some indetail or suggest any sample code.